# How did I apply to a job 146 weeks ago which was posted 14 days ago?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, time

[This job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/134022/senior-full-stack-net-web-application-developer-maplarge?so=y&pg=1&offset=6&q=.net&r=true) was posted 14 days ago, but I applied 146 weeks ago.

[image]

Comment: It's recommended not to time travel if you're applying to jobs, normally offers don't last 3 years

Comment: Yeah, my sonic screwdriver has been malfunctioning.  Sorry.

Comment: It's likely that they renewed or are reusing an existing job ad. Seeing a job ad you know is old suddenly show up as being recently posted is unfortunately very common across job sites.

Comment: Maybe change "Posted X days ago" to "Updated X days ago" when the posting is indeed an update to an existing job?

Comment: Did you actually apply for the job and it's just saying the wrong date? Or is it making up an application attempt that was never made?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sub>I'm a developer on the Stack Overflow Jobs platform</sub>

In this case, the system shows the job as being re-posted 14 days ago, while its original posting was a while back. I'm afraid you haven't actually travelled through time, sorry.

Comment: Bummer. There's good money to be had in a working time machine.