# Why is the Posted Date on Jobs completely made up?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

There's a particular job I've been seeing in my feed for the past few months, when I saw it I gave it a reaction.

The last few times I've seen it (over the last few months), it's always said a date in the past week or so. It currently shows

> Posted 6 days ago

I know this is not true because I see my own (and others) likes/dislikes which are certainly months old by now.

I'm going to check back on this exact job in a few days to see if it still says 6 days :D

---

I propose adding the actual UTC of posting when hovering - like we do on all other dates within StackOverflow.

Additionally, we should be more honest on what that date means.

Comment: Chances are the same job is being _re_-posted, so you're not actually seeing the _exact_ same posting. Probably as a way of bumping it or something. Like in [this case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401191/how-did-i-apply-to-a-job-146-weeks-ago-which-was-posted-14-days-ago) where a position was re-posted 3 years after a user applied for a position.

Comment: @Nick makes sense. That's what I figured and addressed it in my final point in the post - we need some more honesty on _what_ that number means... if they repost the same job - it's still posted on the original date - it can say something like "Featured 6 days ago"...

Comment: I don't see any grounds why you believe "posted date" is not a date when job was posted and hence how using UTC or adding explanation of "data when job was posted" would be useful. (indeed you may have a point that reposting may be questionable but it is not what post talks about)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If it's the date when the job was *re*posted, then it's *not* the date the job was posted. Words mean things.

Comment: Yeah words are very tricky that way.

Comment: @StackOverthrow: I agree, but on the other hand, nothing would stop them from removing the posting and posting a new, identical posting afresh. If the goal is to look like a hot, limited time offer position, I can definitely see recruiters doing that if the "real age" is made more apparent.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: "nothing would stop them from removing the posting and posting a new, identical posting afresh" - well, StackOverflow should stop them from doing that...

Comment: @Crowman: Aside from manual search, how would they stop simple changes to defeat hash checks? Even if those checks are made practical and implemented, how long is it before the same posting (perhaps for a legitimately identical position) is allowed again? And more importantly, is the problem really worth the effort it would entail to stop it? This just doesn't seem like enough of a problem to be worth addressing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: At an absolute minimum, they could take action and sanction offenders when this behavior is detected and flagged, just like almost all bad behavior on this site is already dealt with. As to whether it's worth it, the age of a job posting is material information which matters to potential applicants, otherwise it wouldn't be there at all, so it's worth it by definition. The appropriate alternative is to remove the posting age altogether, not to deliberately permit misrepresentations to be made.

Comment: @WELZ I agree that it's annoying but literally every other job board does the same thing with the date. I think this site lets you dismiss an ad/posting if you don't want to see it again.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Posting an ad costs money, right? That's why sleazy recruiters have always tried to game it. They used to edit the same posting to advertise a completely different job. Updating the "posted" date might have been an ill-considered half-solution to that problem.

Answer (score -1):

The comments already pointed out that this was a re-posting date, but I would like to give more context about why you might see this.

First, a little about how job boards work. Many job boards will charge a flat fee whenever they post it; they pay a specific fee and are allowed to have the job posted for a certain length of time (commonly 30 days). Under this arrangement, if they unpost the job and re-post it, it would typically result in a new fee to the company.  Similarly, after the 30 days it up, it expires and they need to re-post

Sometimes, companies that post a large number of jobs can buy "blocks" of postings or have other similar arrangements where they're allowed a certain number of postings in a certain time period.

Finally, for a couple of job boards, companies buy a specific duration for a job - for example, they'll give you a 2 month period you can unpost and re-post as many times as you want. At the end of 2 months, you'll need to pay another fee to keep it up on the board.

So, whether they're permitted to un-post and re-post without generating additional fees is likely dictated by their contract with Stack Exchange, so it might not be all that simple for them to change. Point being, what you're suggesting is *not* just a technical change - it could also entail a fee structure or contract change too.

It's also possible that the company in question is willing to fork over extra money to unpost and re-post it before the normal expiration date - i.e. that doing this *does* result in additional fees, but the company doing this doesn't care. If that's true, then Stack Exchange is probably not going to be willing to change that - I'm sure they'd be perfectly content to accept the additional fees.

In addition to expiration date, companies may un-post and re-post the job to make changes to the job ad, or to hire additional people against the job. At least some applicant tracking systems distinguish between a job and a position. A company might want to hire 5 junior engineers or 7 machine operators, for example. In this case, they probably wouldn't bother to create a new job or a new job ad in their ATS - they'd just indicate that they wanted to hire multiple people for the job.

One other reason that they'd want to do this is if they hired someone that didn't work out for some reason (e.g. they were "no-show" for the job, or the candidate decided that they didn't like the job after a few days).

Comment: I'm curious why this is getting downvoted.

Comment: I'd guess there's some eye roll here because of course there are reasons for it, just like there are reasons for every common pattern contributing to the general malaise of job listings... The request here is to mitigate this one in some fashion, so as to make this less confusing.

Comment: @Shog9 Good point. It does seem to be a rather tiresome aspect of job postings. It's not necessarily quite as simple to mitigate as the OP's saying, though, since there are non-technical factors too. Maybe one solution would be to have the original posting date or something.

Comment: Maybe something like "first published on ...", "last updated on..." and bumping should not count as updated really.